# Elementary question on Young Symmetrizer

Tags: representation-theory

Let $T$ be a Young tableaux (rows of decreasing length, filled by integers $1,2,\ldots,n$), of shape $\lambda=(\lambda_1,\cdots,\lambda_k)$

Let
$P$ be the subgroup of $S_n$ consisting of permutations preserving rows of $T$.

In the group algebra $\mathbb{C}S_n$, consider the element
$$
a=\sum_{\sigma\in P}\sigma.
$$

> $S_n$ acts on $V^{\otimes n}$ by permuting factors; the image of element $(a\in \mathbb{C}S_n)\rightarrow \mathrm{End}(V^{\otimes n})$ is just the subspace
> $$
> Im(a)=\mathrm{Sym}^{\lambda_1}V \otimes \mathrm{Sym}^{\lambda_2}V \otimes\cdots \otimes \mathrm{Sym}^{\lambda_k}V \subset V^{\otimes n}$$
> where the inclusion on the right is obtained by grouping the factors of $V^{\otimes n}$ according to the rows of  tableaux $T$.

**Question:** It may be trivial, but I do not understand the above statement (from Fulton-Harris, Rep. Theory). In the endomorphism ring, I could not get how $Im(a)$ is subspace of the form mentioned above? Can one explain it?

Comment: See [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2785642/305862)

Comment: @Jean Marie: This solves my doubt. Thanks for the comment.